# htaccess redirect www to non-www without changing in address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, no-www

I have this address

```
http://name.com/category/1/news
```

I use this code in htaccess to force open page without www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I open `http://www.name.com/category/1/news` then I redirect to

```
http://name.com/category.php?id=1&slug=news
```

Here is my full htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ news.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Keep `301` rule at top and clear browser cache.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ news.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L]
```