# I want that all my webpages have the same domain without the subdomain www

Tags: .htaccess

I have the same exact one page, which you can reach with [this](https://xn--dortmund-schlsseldienst-opc.de/leistungen.html) link
an with [that](https://www.xn--dortmund-schlsseldienst-opc.de/leistungen.html) one.
1. As you can see, the second link has the subdomain www. in it but I want that   every one of my webpages have a domain without www.
I tried several redirects in the .htaccess file and i put this file in my domain root folder but none of them worked for me.
I have 13 webpages, which you can reach with and without www. and how can I just have the versions without www.?
The curious thing is that my starting page automatically redirects to the version without www. even if I type in the domain with www. It would be great if all my sites were reachable like my starting page. 
2. Is this duplicate content and if yes, is it bad for the ranking of my website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect www to non-www without changing in address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160776/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-without-changing-in-address)

Comment: Hey it worked for me!! Thanks :)))